# UIScrollView with many tables side by side, with paging

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to implement a scrollview with different tables side by side. Similar to the one on the YouTube app where there are different tables for "About", "Suggested" and "Comments". I tried doing this by first adding individual tableViews to a UIScrollView. In this case the parents scrollView didn't scroll sideways even after I enabled paging. In my second attempt I tried making a tableView with 2 sections. But here, the different cells just got added as rows instead of getting added in a separate "page" or "column". Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: can you post a screen shot of what do you have and what do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you set the content-size of your "outer" scroll-view to the right dimensions?

For example if you have the horizontal setup of 3 table views you want to nest (as mentioned in your question: "About", "Suggested" and "Comments"), then the `contentSize` property of your UIScrollView must be set to 3 times the width of your nested view (i.e. the 3 UITableViews).

Check out the docs for [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and the `contentSize` property.
Maybe also check out the [ScrollViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904) examples by Apple.

Comment: Well. I did this in my storyboard file since the size of the scrollview is going to be static. Then I checked the size using NSLog statements. It showed that the size of the ScrollView is fine. but it doesn't scroll sideways. It only reads the scroll events of the child table.

Comment: Hm, that's quite interesting! Normally your set-up should work out-of-the box because UIKit is *normally* smart enough on intelligently detecting and dealing with proper touch-event propagation. Can you post your some code maybe?

Comment: And to get things clear! :) => the contentSize is not the same as the frame of the UIScrollView! So don't mix this up! The contentSize is normally larger than the frame and should expand or shrink as "pages" are added/removed!

Comment: And i suppose user interaction is enabled for all of your views, right?

Comment: You were right. I had confused the bounds with the contentSize. The horizontal scrolling works now. :) But it scrolls diagonally as well. How do I disable that? :)

Comment: Ok, good to hear! :) For the diagonal scrolling: I'd say it's still a issue with your content size! The content size is probably still larger then 1 screen size or so.